# Log vscode command execution for shortcuts mapped to multiple commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Is there a way to find what vscode command was executed. For example, 'tab' is a keyboard shortcut for a lot of commands (depending on the context). Now I wish to find a way to display which specific command was pressed (insertSnippet or insertNextSuggestion or something else...) in the console or anywhere

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this -- but I'm curious as to WHY you want to do this?

Comment: 1. would help create a proper 'macro recording' extension. 2. it would allow me to quickly find out the vscode commands for various tasks instead of me looking it up in documentation/examples for hours. It would save me enormous amounts of time.